# How to convert query results to string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, string-formatting

I am storing HTML in a varchar(max) field there can be many of these fields returned in a data set I need to basically concat them into a string so I can add them to my control any idea's?

so for example

```
result 1: <h5> This is a result  </h5>
result 2: <h5> This is a result  </h5>
result 3: <h5> This is a result  </h5>
result 4: <h5> This is a result  </h5>
```

I need the results set to be parsed to a string that would be like:

```
<h5> This is a result  </h5>
<h5> This is a result  </h5>
<h5> This is a result  </h5>
<h5> This is a result  </h5>
```

I am returning the result from a stored procedure because I will be allowing the user to only execute stored procedures and they will not have any table permissions

Comment: which procedure you are using at backend?

Comment: so in other words: you have x strings and want them concatinated? if so, what about a stringbuilder?

Comment: I don't really understand this question. I think the grammar is hindering it.

Comment: Same here. I cannot understand the problem...

Answer (score 1):

```
string results = someStoredProcCall();
results = Regex.Replace(results, @"result [0-9]+: ", "");
```

Comment: If I understand him correctly, "result x" isn't being returned, it's merely how he's labeling the returned rows.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist That could be. I don't really understand exactly what he's asking (no one else does either apparently), but that's how I interpreted it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, your HTML will be in the database and needs to be rendered in the control?  If yes, I would setup a literal control and when loading the data, set the property of the literal to render the stored HTML results.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < dsResults.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    sb.Append(PrepareResult(dsResults.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()));
}

litControl.Text = sb.ToString();


public string PrepareResult(string result)
{
    return result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<"));
}
```

This is free hand code, so you may need to adjust slightly, I think the concept is clear.  HTH

Comment: strings are immutable so this code will keep allocating a fresh set of memory each time the loop iterates.

Comment: @Ben Robinson - is that better :) I think it answers the question though, don't you think?  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL Stored Procedure you could do the following

```
DECLARE @PartHTML VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @FullHTML VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE CURSOR HTMLCursor FOR (SELECT FieldWithHTML FROM TableWithHTML)
OPEN CURSOR HTMLCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM HTMLCursor INTO @PartHTML

While (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
    SET @FullHTML = @FullHTML + @PartHTML + CHAR(13)
    FETCH NEXT FROM HTMLCursor INTO @PartHTML

END
CLOSE HTMLCursor
DEALLOCATE HTMLCursor
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ:

```
string[] results = ...
string resultsStr = results.Aggregate((a,b) => a + b);
```

or...

```
MyEntity[] results = ...
string resultsStr = results.Select(r => r.SomeColumn).Aggregate((a,b) => a + b);
```